# Draw function in custom View giving problems (Android Honeycomb)

Tags: android, drawing, android-3.0-honeycomb, custom-view

I made a game (called [Block Crusher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher)) that's downloadable from the Market Today. Since there are more and more HoneyComb tablet's come out these days, I wanted to make my game compatible for those tablet's.

But I run into some problems when I tried to run my Game on the Motorola Xoom.

In this game I have a custom View. This view draws the game board onto the screen. It draws blocks in different kind of colors. When you click on them you destroy the blocks and the rest will fall down.

On a pre-Honeycomb device this works without problems. On the Motorola Xoom I have drawing problems. Somehow the old position of the blocks is not wiped out and that makes the blocks very long, instead of falling down. (Not sure if I wrote this down that it's understandable, but I hope so).

I even added the following code to my draw function to completly wipe the canvas before drawing a new frame on it:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Disable super.draw call to make the control transparent.
    // super.draw(canvas);

    // Clear the entire screen before starting drawing.
    mTransparantPaint = new Paint();
    mTransparantPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mTransparantPaint);
```

But somehow I have some problems with redrawing when the blocks are falling down.

Anyone knows why I'm having this problems on Honeycomb?  Has it anything to do with the hardware accellerated 2D graphics pipeline of HoneyComb? I have not enabled or disabled anything for that.

If you have a Honeycomb tablet and want to see the problem, you can download a development build from http://peerke.no-ip.info/morbur/Svn-267.1/MorburActivity-release.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the super.draw(canvas) is always needed on Honeycomb. That didn't give problems in previous versions of android.